# mvn package does not create jars for dependencies with compile scope

Tags: java, maven, jar

I come from Gradle and I am switching one of my projects to Maven. Gradle automatically created the jar for those dependencies that had `<scope>compile</scope>`, but it seems Maven does not do that? Is there a way to tell Maven to create jars for my scope compile dependencies?

Here is a snippet of my pom.xml for which I would expect jars created somewhere in my `target` folder

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yubico</groupId>
        <artifactId>yubico-validation-client2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Comment: You may need to use `maven-dependency-plugin` if you ant your dependencies copied to a folder under `target` folder

Comment: The scope annotation in maven is to indicate that the dependency is required at compile time.

Comment: maven already has its own repo `.m2` directory where all the dependencies are there. Until and unless you specifically mention

Comment: @Compass `compile` scope is default one. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project` and **all** means compile, runtime and test classpaths.

Comment: You can check this as an example [Build a project with dependencies](https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-build-java-project-including-all-dependencies-using-maven-maven-resources-maven-dependency-maven-jar-plugin-tutorial/). You will need to either use `maven-dependency-plugin` to just build a jar which has dependencies inside or if you are building an executable then you will have to use `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: @Ivan yes I was referring to the fact that it doesn't actually "compile" anything as opposed to indicating the dependency should be compiled.

Comment: Telling maven you are using dependencies like you have defined in your pom file. This will create jar files of those dependencies cause they already exist in maven central. You will get those jar's (dependencies) during the compilation on your classpath that you can compile your code...If you like to create an executable jar you have go the path which has been suggest by others already. Maven is NOT Gradle...

Comment: @Ivan that's what I have done, but since in Gradle it's much simpler than that I was wondering if there is a way to tell Maven to just build jars from selected dependencies rather than having to specify each dependency twice, once in the `<dependency>` and then again in the `<artifactItem>` of the `maven-dependency-plugin`

Comment: @Acewin `maven-assemply-plugin` would create a fat jar with all the (unnecessary dependencies) and it would be much longer for me to exclude them rather than include only the ones I actually need with `maven-dependency-plugin`. I still think Gradle handle this in a much elegant way and was hoping Maven would offer something similar

Comment: You do not need to use`artifactItem` on dependency-plugin for that

Comment: yes I do otherwise it would just copy everything, all the dependencies and I don't want/need that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to handle this elegantly like Gradle does. I had to manually import dependencies using `maven-dependency-plugin` to create jars for each and every dependency I found I needed when I launched the application (i.e. all those that had `compile` scope).

So fo every block of `<dependency>` scoped `compile` I had to use an `<artifactItem>` inside `maven-dependency-plugin`, here's an example for rollbar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rollbar</groupId>
    <artifactId>rollbar-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is what worked for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>com.rollbar</groupId>
                <artifactId>rollbar-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```